# Trying to create an invisible button to change an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have an invisible button on a small part of the page to change the background image.

But, **the button doesn't change the image** to the one specified.

```js
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

image.addEventListener('click', function(){
  changeImage();
});

function changeImage(){
  image.src = 'img/lab.svg';
}
```

```html
<img src="img/vault.svg" alt="">
<button id="myImage"> </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse your button reference (variable `image`) with the `<img>` element.

Make sure you use sensible names (for your variables *and* IDs) to avoid confusions.

---

You save the button reference in the variable `image`, and try to change its `src` property.

Instead, you should assign to the image's `src` attribute:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('image-button');
const image = document.getElementById('image');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  changeImage();
});

function changeImage(){
  image.src = 'img/lab.svg';
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="img/vault.svg" alt="">
<button id="image-button"> </button>
```

**Note**: I changed the variable names and element IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `image.onload` and `image.onerror` to understand what's happening.

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

image.addEventListener('click', function(){
    changeImage();
});
image.onerror = function(e) { console.log('Loading failed', e); }
image.onload= function(e) { console.log('Loading successful', e); }

function changeImage(){
    image.src = 'img/lab.svg';
}
```

Comment: it says  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code (a missing `}` to close your function maybe). Or is there another `addEventListener` somewhere causing the error?